# problems with 'this' in OOP JS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, this

I am making a game and using Prototype JS framework for an easy work with objects.
I made my own methods for non DOM events among my own objects.

StageObject is the child of Screen object and it's method load() loads the image of the object and as soon as it's loaded fires the event.
Here it is:

```
var StageObject = Class.create(Screen, {...}) 

StageObject.addMethods({
    /*.....*/
    load:function(){
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.src = "./src/img/"+this.src;        
        this.img.onload = this.objectLoadedHandler();                           
    }, 
})
```

objectLoadedHandler belongs to StageObject. It fires another event, **whitch handler is in Screen object, not in StageObject**. The problem is that inside of this second handler **'this' does not point at the current object** (Screen). I have not figured out what it points at, but I can not reach the proberties of Screen object which I need for further calculations. Please give me a piece of advice about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.img.onload = this.objectLoadedHandler.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thank you do much! I should have spent more time learning Prototype. I found this http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind and it explained everything to me.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the problem is that you are filling too much object oriented stuff in your code. If you use `this` on every second line of code you will invariably run into a situation where you can't grasp the implications any more. I'm not sure if I should attribute it to not knowing Prototype or to the code piece in your post missing some vital parts for the understanding, but I don't know what is wrong either.

In any case, simply resolving this issue will not solve the more general problem that you write code too complicated for yourself to understand. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103299/help-me-understand-this-brian-kernighan-quote

In JavaScript `this` is a somewhat dangerous tool, some people use it for quite simple stuff, and sometimes that works okay. But when you pass around functions as parameters of other functions etc. it grows way harder to understand what `this` means in any given context. Personally I almost never use `this` in my code, and I almost never attach functions to objects. There are some complex problems where the heavy OO style is useful, but in most cases I'd say it does more harm than good.

Comment: Well I think if you make something like a form cheking tool or stuff like that you don't need to use OOP at all, or use it just sometimes, but in my case, I found it better to use OO style because I want to have minimized connections between my objects to be able to change the logical parts separately without having them influnced each other. Using Prototype 'bind()' I know exactly on what scope a method is fixated so it's allright now. Still, thanks for the advice.

Comment: "Minimized connections between objects to be able to change the logical parts separately without having them influnced each other." It sounds fancy, but remember, it's a non-feature, it doesn't actually do anything. Supposedly it should make your code easier to write and maintain, you ought to question whether you actually achieve that. It seems to me that very few programmers question the "best practices" that they are taught.

Comment: "Supposedly it should make your code easier to write and maintain" - it does! I can provide an example if needed..

Comment: Of course you can find an example where your method fits perfectly. But the question is if your everyday code is a good example?

Comment: Sorry for downvoting but IMO you completely overlook the benefits of **inheritance** and **encapsulation**. I find the hardest code to understand is that which tries to clump everything in the global namespace, it just doesn't scale. Of course it's up to the programmer to objectively choose the best paradigm for the situation and if Ilya knows most about the situation then he is best qualified to choose.

Comment: @clockworkgeek You don't have to toss everything into the global namespace just because you don't use the most fancy of features. Functions should use their own namespace, they can even have their own private functions. And I'm of course not against using data objects. If you deal with a lot of data most of it should be in object trees, arrays or whatever fit the situation. Most of all, I'd just rather not attach methods to my data objects since in most cases that does not achieve anything but possible `this` confusion.

Comment: It's up to the progremmer to decide whether to use OO or not, **BUT** I can not imagine a good game (and any other advanced project) without OO (It's possible to make it but it would be non maintainable, hard for undrstanding and mixed logically). A good object structure is the base of any advanced programm. I can show my code to a programmer without any further explanations and they would understand it and be able to maintain and extend. Objects speak for themselves.

Comment: @IlyaSoin, Nothing wrong about OO, and in the cases where you really need that sort of features classic OO is great. It just seems to me that some programmers use advanced object structures for everything, never questioning if it's the right tool for the job.